# "Good going" or "well going"?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

The colloquialism "good going!", said as a praise, uses the adjective "good" in reference to the verb "going". Shouldn't the adverb "well" be used instead? Why not?

Comment: The 'going' is used as a noun here, as in horse racing: "The going is good." You can also say "Well done!" where 'done' is a verb (participle).